# cordova is not installing

Tags: android, node.js, cordova, npm-install

I'm trying to install cordova in win7. But while running `npm install -g cordova` on cmd prompt, i m getting the following error:

```
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601

npm ERR! argv "c:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "c:\\Program Files\\nodejs
\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "cordova"
npm ERR! node v6.2.1

npm ERR! npm  v3.9.3

npm ERR! code ECONNABORTED

npm ERR! errorno ECONNABORTED

npm ERR! syscall connect

npm ERR! connect ECONNABORTED 103.245.222.162:443

npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
```

Comment: did you ran cmd as Administrator ?

Comment: Do you have any proxy?

Comment: @SharayuKulkarni that yes means you ran cmd as an admin and is also behind a proxy?

Comment: @SharayuKulkarni is this your first time using `npm`? If so, I think your proxy is blocking npm .

Comment: what can i do now?

Comment: @SharayuKulkarni try this: `npm config set proxy http://proxy.example.com:8080`

Comment: @SharayuKulkarni is the error still the same after configuring the proxy of npm?

Answer (score 0):

Its proxy issue, run that command without proxy

Comment: No,again it is not working. I've installed the prerequisite for cordova like (node.js,git),but still it is not working.

Comment: Is there any other alternatives?

Comment: @SharayuKulkarni Did u set the Environmental path for Node.js? or running npm command where Node is installed? give full screenshot of installation